# Shall I filter the foam from wine

Tags: fermentation, wine

I am brewing apple wine. There is a layer of white foam forming at the top. Shall I remove it or it is ok to leave it like this?[image]

Comment: looks fine, I don't think you need to do anything at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO this looks like a normal and vigorous fermentation. There is no need to disturb it or remove any foam layer. My advice would be to leave it alone for at least a month (if not 2 or more) and then see how it is doing.

It looks like the carboy on the right has had a very energetic fermentation!